# Where is more efficient or convenient to sort data?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Java Web app, using JPA for storage, and following the MVC pattern. In many methods I have to return a `List<Product>` which I should order by its name. Where is it better to include the *sorting* logic?

In a controller method like this one, in the `Query` itself:

```
   public List<Product> obtainProductList()
   {
      Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Product g ORDER BY g.name");
      List<Product> ret = query.getResultList();

      if (ret == null)
      {
         return new ArrayList<>();
      }
      else
      {
         return ret;
      }
   }
```

Or maybe in a Manager class at the moment of retrieving the data to the page itself?:

```
   public List<Product> getProducts()
   {
      products = controller.obtainProductList();
      //Sort the list by comparators, for example;
      return this.products;
   }
```

Currently I'm doing it by the first method, but I'm open to new ways.

Comment: Use it in the query. The database is optimized for such operations

Comment: It is not an option to sort on server side especially when you need to sort on criteria which come from a huge join. Let the database do the work, JPA is intended to let you do this.

Comment: Unless you know something special about the data that the database doesn't then leave it to the DB as @verbose-mode said.

Comment: See the last exemple of http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/order. IMO, it is the best way because it provides type checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sorting most be done by the DB server of course, but where to put your logic?, 
My answer is not to put it into your controller. This sorted data is needed by your frontend right, but maybe you have(will have to) to use it on many other places, so the controller action responsibility is just to provide it, but collaborating with a service/provider/ repository which should be in charge of providing the sorted data and the controller action should just pass it through. This way controllers are easier to test and your data is more reusable. Follow Slim Controllers - Slim Views approach and SRP.